# What is the meaing of 'greyed out' questions?

Tags: support

'greyed out' or faded questions seemed to appear for me about a month ago.  I do not remember seeing them before that. What is the meaning of this?  Who does it?  How is it done?  What is its purpose?

I looked at the edit history an could not find anything.  There is one related answer "A greyed answer" but it does not answer my questions.  Maybe 'greyed out' is not the correct term.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions are greyed out if they are tagged with a tag belonging to your "ignored tags" (you can also choose to hide these questions completely). You should see your ignored tags on the front page in the right hand side bar at the top, just below current featured meta questions and your watched tags.

Comment: That was it!! Something was unintentionally added to ignored tags. Thanks